# QIODevice::size() and QIODevice::bytesAvailable() always return 0

Tags: c++, qt, qiodevice

I'm writing an emulator that requires me to continuously push generated raw audio samples to a `QAudioOutput`. This is achieved by writing bytes to the underlying `QIODevice` like so:

```
Qt_speaker::Qt_speaker()
{
    QAudioFormat fmt;
    fmt.setSampleRate(44100);
    fmt.setChannelCount(1);
    fmt.setSampleSize(sizeof(uint8_t)*8);
    fmt.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    fmt.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    fmt.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(fmt)) {
        qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.\n"
                      "If you're running a Debian system, try manually installing Qt's"
                      "multimedia plugins with\n"
                      "\t'sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins'";
        toggle(false);
        return;
    }
    output_ = new QAudioOutput(fmt, nullptr);
    output_->setBufferSize(44100);
    //connect(output_, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),
            //this, SLOT(output_state_changed(QAudio::State)));
    device_ = output_->start();

}

void Qt_speaker::push_samples(const gameboy::Raw_audio &a)
{
    device_->write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(a.data()), a.size());
}
```

I want to keep track of the number of samples queued because the sound drives the speed of emulation, and consequently, of the raw audio samples being generated. Trying to call `QIODevice::read()` always returns 0. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should notify signal of QAudioInput in order to behave according to the samples "consumed" by QAudioInput.